# Ошибка метода доставки WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Я создал плагин для метода доставки  WooCommerce. Но возникает ошибка при добавлении его в зону доставки. Недостаточно опыта, чтобы понять, откуда это и как исправить.

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings_html')
    at Object.success (wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.5.2:1:11617)
    at c (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7:25304)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7:26053)
    at l (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7:77782)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7:80265)
(anonymous) @ wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.5.2:1
c @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
fireWith @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
l @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
load (async)
send @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
ajax @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:10
e.<computed> @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:10
ce.<computed> @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
onAddShippingMethodSubmitted @ wc-shipping-zone-methods.min.js?ver=8.5.2:1
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
v.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
trigger @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
each @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
each @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
trigger @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
nextButton @ backbone-modal.min.js?ver=8.5.2:1
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
v.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=wp-polyfill-inert,regenerator-runtime,wp-polyfill,wp-hooks,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,jquer&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=y-ui-sortable&ver=6.4.3:7
```